# Rest Wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to test my Rest Wcf service from the Browser.
WhenI am trying to send some values from browser I am getting the following error.
"The message cannot be processed at the receiver, 
due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.
Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree."

Then I added [ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)].
then I am getting a different error.

"Due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. 
This may be because of either a contract mismatch 
(mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or 
a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.
Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding 
(including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None)."

Can we pass values to a Rest Wcf Service from a browser??

I am trying to passing following  values from the browser.

```
http://mywebsite/Service1.svc/mymethod/Firstname,Lastname,LosAngles,CA
```

here is my web.confg file

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>              
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Wcfservice1.ServiceBehavior" name="="Wcfservice1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Wcfservice1.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>    
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>        
        <behavior name="Wcfservice1.ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>    
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I can't find the `<webHttp/>` endpoint behavior in your config. Unless you've specified the "WebServiceHostFactory" in the `Service1.svc` file this is missing, and might even account for the error you're getting.

Comment: Really. Where do I add <webHttp/> tag. Whatever the code is there in web.config is generated by VS2008.I am new to wcf.Can you please provide me some code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: <behaviors><endpointBehaviors><behavior name="REST"><webHttp/></behavior></endpointBehaviors></behaviors>. And you need to link to that behavior from your endpoint: <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="REST" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="..." />

Comment: Hi ,Thanks for the help. It seems the problem with the error is fixed.But Now I am getting "Method not allowed" dialog is displayed. But my method is POST only which sends data to wcf and wcf saves the data to Database. Why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you didn't enable the `<webHttp/>` behavior on the REST endpoint. Add this inside the `<behaviors/>` element in your config file:

```
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="REST">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

Then, change the `<endpoint/>` element like this:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="REST" contract="Wcfservice1.IService1">
```

Comment: Hi ,Thanks for the help. It seems the problem with the error is fixed.But Now I am getting "Method not allow" dialog is displayed. But my method is POST only which sends data to wcf and wcf saves the data to Database. Why I am getting this error.

Comment: Did you put a `[WebInvoke]` attribute on your service operation? Look here for an introduction to writing WCF 3.5 REST services (you're using VS 2008, right?): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412178%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: yes I did. Here is my Post method:[OperationContract]
            [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/SaveData/{param1},{param2},{param3}", Method = "POST")]
            string SaveData(string param1, string param2, string param3);

Comment: You're invoking this in the browser, right? In that case the request will be a GET, not POST! Sorry, missed that bit earlier.

Comment: I didnt get you. You mean I cannot invoke a Post method from browser.Then from where can I invoke.

Comment: If you type a URL as the one in your question in the browser address bar and navigate to it the request will always be a HTTP GET. That's just how browsers work. You can send a POST by (1) using a <form> with a submit button on a HTML page, (2) using jQuery's $.post() function in javascript, or (3) using a .Net WCF REST client app (to name just a few). If you still want to be able to use the browser, replace `[WebInvoke]` with `[WebGet]` or `Method="POST"` with `Method="GET"` in your service implementation.

Comment: Is it possible can I use Fiddler to test this, what could be the url. I think for Fiddler you need to add some "ipv4.fiddler" infront of the url, I am not sure. Thanks for your time